# Accessing ip camera from another LAN

Tags: networking

how can i access the IP camera from outside my LAN? In LAN i use 192.168.1.3 to access but which address should i use to access it from another LAN

Answer (score 1):

You can't just access LAN address, you must forward the traffic.

If you can access your router settings, find port forwarding option. There you can forward incoming traffic to camera.

If you are accessing your camera from browser you need to forward port 80. There may be more ports which needs to be forwarded, use the manual to find them or the camera settings.

If the camera is Vivotek I can write you more detailed instructions.

If you need help with router settings, provide us the model.

Edit: When you forward the traffic you should use your network address to access camera from outside, which you can see when you type "my ip address" in google.

If your traffic is filtered by other routers or firewalls, they may permit access.

About Edimax:
Manual for router: [here](http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/manual/Wireless/BR-6204WLG/BR-6204WLg_Manual.zip)
Here on page 73 you can find information about portforwarding.

Camera settings: [here](http://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC0QFjAC&url=http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/FAQ/IP-Camera/General-IP-Cam/ConfigureIPcam-RouterIC3000.pdf&rct=j&q=Edimax%20camera%20ports&ei=zH8lTqjLDsWOswbeurXDCQ&usg=AFQjCNH_wl_nrp97cSbm2b6xnbazgQtFUw&sig2=F_ELoXURuHrb5ShyMhS8vw&cad=rja)
Here you will find the ports needed for the settings and general information about the scheme.

Comment: my camera is Edimax and router is Edimax BR-6204wlg